# jQuery ID Selection dynamic

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, dynamic

Not Sure if this can be done, the way I am approaching it. Here goes nothing. I am echoing images from a php upload script, each img has a unique ID which starts at A1,A2,A3,A4 and so on. Now I can select That img ID and create the action I want, however I have to do it for every ID, I wont be able to do this as new ones are created, How would I tell jQuery to do the same thing to A1 (A2,A3) Some sort of Increment.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#1 ").hover(
   function(){
    $("#A1").slideDown();
   },

   function(){
     $("#A1").slideUp();
   });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#2 ").hover(

   function(){
     $("#A2").slideDown();
   },
   function(){
     $("#A2").slideUp();
   });
});
```

**PHP**

```
$i= 0; while(($file = $myDir->read()) !==false){
  if(!is_dir($file)){
    $i++;
    //echo "Filename: $file<br/>";
    echo "<div id='images'>";
    echo "<p>";
    echo "<a id='$i'href=\"display/$file\"><img src=\"thumbs/$file\" /> </a>\n";
    echo "</p>";
    echo"</div>";
    echo "<div id='imageHolder' >";
    echo "<img id='A$i' style='display:none' src=\"display/$file\" />";
    echo"</div>";
  }
}
```

Comment: What kind of elements are your "#1 " and #2 " elements?  What is your html structure (are the images inside of your #1 and #2 elements?)?  Are you loading the new images via ajax or only on initial pageload?

Comment: The #1 #2 elements are anchor tags, I added my html/php what I would like to do is have that same number increment for the elements I am selecting so I dont have to write each one out, when I add a new one via the upload script.

Comment: I would recommend caution with having IDs start with a number, you may run into difficulties in certain situations with certain browsers. Here's someone else's take on the matter: http://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are your new items being generated? On page load, or are you using an ajax request through jQuery?  In either case you can select all elements that start with a certain value (i.e. "A") this way:

```
$("a").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).find(img[id^='A']).slideDown();
    },
    function(){
        $(this).find(img[id^='A']).slideUp();
});
```

Somebody feel free to help me out if I'm off here.

**UPDATE**

Thanks guys - What about something like this?

```
$("a").hover(
    function(){
        id = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#A"+id).slideDown();
    },
    function(){
        id = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#A"+id).slideUp();
});
```

This looks for all links on the page and uses the ID (per your code) to look for the slide items. If you're creating them dynamically you'll want to put this inside a function and call it again on ajaxComplete.

Comment: That would work however they perform different actions for each unique dive, They are showing something different on hover. This way shows them all at once.

Comment: Your selector is correct, but I don't think it'll help. He needs to trap an event that occurs when an image is added to the page to add the hover event to it. Your example will animate all the images on a hover event; I think he just wants the image that is hovered to animate.

Answer (score 1):

I would have a javascript array that holds all the object ids. Then you can just loop through the array and for each id do the work you want to do.

Comment: I am a little confused as to how this will look, I havent done arrays in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery.live() for "permanent" event handlers (in case you are dynamically adding images to the page) or use jQuery.each() for iterating through all instances.

In the end it would be something like this (without using live events):

```
$("a:has(img.my_image)").each(function(){
    $(this).hover(
        function(){$(this).slideDown();},
        function(){$(this).slideUp();}
    );
});
```

Comment: This is close but has 2 problems: 1) it assumes that the image is inside the <a> tag which is something he hasn't told us and 2) it's sliding the <a> up and down rather than the image, which is what he wants to do.  To slide the image your third and fourth lines need to be more like function(){$('img.my_image',this).slideDown();},function(){$('img.my_image',this).slideUp();}